# How to change CSS style for panZoomBar?

Tags: openlayers-2

How do I change or add the CSS style for `panZoomBar`?

I.e. to change the panup, pandown, panleft, etc hover in CSS by attaching the class in CSS for those...  and which class should I create it in...

Answer (score 2):

i got the answer for my own question partially one month back but i forgot to post it here so that others can make use of it......   i have done the panzoombar changes using css it self with some changes javascript...........

```
.olControlPanup {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:-44px -22px;
  position:relative;
  height:25px;
  width:42px;
  left:5px;
  top:-1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.olControlPanup:hover {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:-44px 0px;
  position:relative;
  height:25px;
  width:42px;
  left:5px;
  top:-1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.olControlPandown {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:-42px -79px;
  position:relative;
  height:25px;
  width:42px;
  left:4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
.olControlPandown:hover {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:-42px -101px;
  position:relative;
  height:25px;
  width:42px;
  left:4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
.olControlPanleft {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:-24px -39px;
  position:relative;
  height:44px;
  width:25px;
  left:5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
.olControlPanleft:hover {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:-2px -39px;
  position:relative;
  height:44px;
  width:25px;
  left:5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
.olControlPanright {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:-82px -41px;
  position:relative;
  height:42px;
  width:25px;
  left:5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}

.olControlPanright:hover {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:-104px -41px;
  position:relative;
  height:42px;
  width:25px;
  left:5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}

.olControlZoomin {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:0px -14px;
  height:24px;
  width:25px;
}

.olControlZoomin:hover {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:0px 167px;
  height:24px;
  width:25px;
}

.olControlZoomout {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:-102px -273px;
  height:24px;
  width:23px;
}

.olControlZoomout:hover {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:-104px -100px;
  height:24px;
  width:23px;
}

.olControlSlider {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:-133px -244px;
  height:9px;
  width:25px;
}

.olControlZoombar {
  background-image:url("../images/ol/zoom-level-buttons.png");
  background-position:-134px -140px;
  width:25px;
}
```

---

### - JAVASCRIPT

```
  var panZoomBar = new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar();
  this.map.addControl( panZoomBar );
  panZoomBar.buttons[0].innerHTML = "<div class=olControlPanup ></div>";
  panZoomBar.buttons[1].innerHTML = "<div class=olControlPanleft ></div>";
  panZoomBar.buttons[2].innerHTML = "<div class=olControlPanright ></div>";
  panZoomBar.buttons[3].innerHTML = "<div class=olControlPandown ></div>";
  panZoomBar.buttons[4].innerHTML = "<div class=olControlZoomin ></div>";
  panZoomBar.buttons[5].innerHTML = "<div class=olControlZoomout ></div>";
  panZoomBar.slider.innerHTML = "<div class=olControlSlider ></div>";
  panZoomBar.zoombarDiv.style.backgroundImage = "";
  panZoomBar.zoombarDiv.style.width = "";
  panZoomBar.zoombarDiv.className = "olControlZoombar";
```

this code is slit lengthier one but it can be made simpler in more ways........

thanks for ur help peoples .....

Comment: Raghu, I'm trying to do something similar. Could you post a full link to the zoom-level-buttons.png file? I'd like to take a look at it. Was it on the Openlayers site somewhere, or?

Answer (score 1):

Raghu please be specific in your tag selection. Your question is not related to 3 out of 5 tags you have used!

In order to change your panZoomBar style, you will have to use

> .olControlPanPanel

class in your css file. The default style is defined in theme/default/style.css file.

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254228/openlayers-pan-zoom-bar-modification

Comment: not for PanPanel i need for PanZoomBar    ei   .olControlPanPanel .olControlPanNorthItemInactive          but when for .olControlPanZoomBar .olControlPanNorthItemInactive is not working